# github "Automatically delete head branches" for multiple repositories

Tags: github, github-actions, github-cli

On Github we can set automatically deletion of branches after merge for a repository  (like explained [here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-the-automatic-deletion-of-branches)). I want to do this for  30 repositories.
Is there a way to do this by script ?
I typically would like to add a file to each repository.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this relatively easily with a script. You can use the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) for this. There is the [following command](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_edit) with which you can switch on the deletion of the branch after a successful merge for a repository:

```sh
gh repo edit [<repository>] --delete-branch-on-merge
```

If you want to start with the CLI, I guess [this](https://cli.github.com/manual/) is a good starting point.

Comment: ```for repo in `gh repo list | awk '{print $1}'` ; do gh repo edit $repo --delete-branch-on-merge ; done```